# Display WriteableBitmap video stream in GUI

Tags: vb.net, winforms, video-streaming

I have the following code snippet that put a stream (NDI) into `WriteableBitmap` ready to be displayed:

```
VideoBitmap = New WriteableBitmap(xres, yres, dpiX, 96.0, PixelFormats.Pbgra32, Nothing)
VideoBitmap.WritePixels(New Int32Rect(0, 0, xres, yres), videoFrame.p_data, bufferSize, stride)
```

It comes from a WPF project that I need to replicate in Windows Form. In the original one this Video Stream was displayed by `VideoSurface.Source = VideoBitmap` where `VideoSurface` was an `Image` component.

I've tried to display it with:

```
Dim videoImg As New Image
videoImg.Source = VideoBitmap
PictureBox1.BackgroundImage = videoImg
```

but the last line gives an error: `Value of type 'Image' cannot be converted to 'Image'.`

How can I figure out this in the best way?

Comment: You alrady have the pointer to to the buffer (`videoFrame.p_data`), the size of the buffer (`bufferSize`) and the Bitmap Stride and the dimensions, so you can build a Bitmap of that dimensions with the same PixelFormat (`PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb`), lock the Bitmap (`Bitmap.LockBits()`), then `Marshal.Copy()` the source buffer to a local buffer then to the `Scan0` pointer of the Bitmap. Or you can use `System.Buffer.MemoryCopy()`. -- Assuming the library that generates your VideoFrame doesn't have an internal method to return a Bitmap (maybe as the argument of an event).

Comment: You can also convert the BitmapSource to a Bitmap, but that's more resource-intensive.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I'm trying to implement this but I can't understand the correct flow. Could you be more clear and didascalic? Or maybe link me to an article where this stuff is explained in a more general way so I can understand better how it works.

Comment: You have a pointer to a buffer (`videoFrame.p_data`), right? You need to copy the data it points to, to a Bitmap data. When you create a Bitmap and call `dim data = [YourBitmap].LockBits([Rectangle], ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)`, then `data.Scan0` is the pointer to the Bitmap data. Now, you can copy the data pointed by `videoFrame.p_data` to the memory location pointed by `data.Scan0`. Either with `Marshal.Copy()` (using an intermediate buffer) or `System.Buffer.MemoryCopy(videoFrame.p_data.ToPointer(), data.Scan0.ToPointer(), [length], [length])`.